# Como desabilitar numberLong no mongo 3?

Tags: mongodb, perl

Como desabilitar `numberLong` no MongoDB 3?

Já tentei `mongo.native_long=0` e não resolveu.

Estou usando `perl` com `mongoexport`

Comment: Qual linguagem você está usando com o mongo?